# Typo in API docs /numbers)

Tags: bug, documentation

https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/numbers

> The motivation for this is to prevent any unpleasant floating point confusion, especially across technologies that offering different floating point precision).

There's a `)` that closes nothing. It doesn't look like there's any suitable opening parenthesis, so I suggest deleting it completely.